# Perl: Find Nth occurrence in a string and return the sub-string up to this occurrence

Tags: perl, indexing, substr

I have the below string in which the delimiter is comma "**,**":

$str = "**abc,123,rty,567,89,,90,gg**"

I want to first find the **N**th occurrence of "," in the above string, let's say I want to find the **5**th occurrence.
In $str this is the comma after element **89**.

Then I want to get that portion of the string $str which starts from 0 and ends up to this **5**th comma, which would be:

"**abc,123,rty,567,89**"

Please advise how can I do this with Perl.

Thank you

Comment: `split` it first on your comma and `join` result array splice (number of elements you want) after that

Answer (score 1):

One simple way using split and list slices:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings; use 5.010; 

my $str = "abc,123,rty,567,89,,90,gg";
say $str;

my $to_fifth = join ',', ( split(',', $str) )[0 .. 4] ;
say $to_fifth;
```

**output**

```
abc,123,rty,567,89,,90,gg
abc,123,rty,567,89
```